# CodeIgniter: Change date format from yyyy-mm-dd to dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: codeigniter, date, date-conversion

I want to change the date format from `yyyy-mm-dd` to `dd-mm-yyyy` but I can't.

This my view:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label labelnya"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i>&nbsp; Tanggal Surat : </label>
<div class="input-group date" id="datepickerDemo17">
    <div class="has-success">
        <input type="text" class="form-control inputan " name="tgl_surat" placeholder="Masukan Waktu Penetapan"/>
    </div>
    <span class="input-group-addon tomb_calender" style="padding: 5px 15px; line-height: 0;">
        <i class=" ion ion-calendar"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

[image: pictures of view]

Comment: Where is your date variable ? Are you using any plugin ?

Comment: can you explain date variable?

Comment: where is your js code ? Are you using datepicker ui or boostrap datepicker  ?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets');?>/styles/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker.css"> , <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets');?>/scripts/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script> just this is

Comment: Show controller code

Comment: i dont have controller code

Answer (score 3):

If you use jquery date picker

```
<script>
    $( function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd-mm-yy" );
    } );
</script>
```

or PHP

```
$date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($old_format_date) );
```

Comment: still cant for jquery datepicker

Comment: Do you try $( "#datepickerDemo17" ).datepicker( format: 'dd-mm-yy' );

Answer (score 1):

#### This view

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label labelnya"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i>&nbsp; Tanggal Surat : </label>
<div class="input-group date" id="datepickerDemo17">
    <div class="has-success">
        <input type="text" class="form-control inputan kusus" id="tgl_surat" data-format="dd-MM-yyyy" name="tgl_surat" placeholder="Masukan Waktu Penetapan"/>
    </div>
    <span class="input-group-addon tomb_calender" style="padding: 5px 15px; line-height: 0;">
        <i class=" ion ion-calendar"></i>
    </span>
</div>
</div>
```

#### This javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function(){
    $("#tgl_surat").datepicker({
        todayHighlight: true,
        format: "dd-mm-yyyy"
    });
})
</script>
```